# How to show that vector $b$ is in the vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that vector $b$ is in the vector space $V$?

vector $b = (0, 4, 7)$, $V = \operatorname{span} \{(1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1), (-1, 0, 1)\}$

Do I use the equation $b = c_1 v_1 +c_2 v_2 +c_3 v_3$ to solve for each $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$? If I do so, what do I do from then?

Comment: You mean, you solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the right direction, but you need to solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3$ and not $v_1, v_2, v_3$. For $b$ to be in $V$, it needs to be a linear combination of the given vectors, that is, $b=c_1(1,2,2)+c_2(1,1,1)+c_3(-1,0,1)$ for some real $c_1, c_2, c_3$, or equivalently $(0,4,7)=(c_1+c_2-c_3,2c_1+c_2,2c_1+c_2+c_3)$. This is equivalent to the system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
c_1+c_2-c_3=0 \\
2c_1+c_2=4 \\
2c_1+c_2+c_3=7
\end{cases}
$$
Can you proceed from here? Solve this system (or show it has a solution).

Comment: Yes, I can do this from here. Essentially, is this question the same as writing vector b as a linear combination of vector V? How do I justify the answers?

Comment: @devil0108 It’s the same as writing the vector $b$ as a linear combination of the given three vectors. The span of a set of vectors is precisely, by definition, the set of all linear combinations of those vectors. Therefore, the existence of a solution to the system above is equivalent to $b$ being in the space $V$, which is spanned by three vectors we started with.